# What is the output format of SHA256

Tags: sha256, sha

What is the output format of the SHA256? It is composed by letters and numbers only? And it is case insensitive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with most (all?) crypto hashes, the output of SHA-256 is *binary* data. How that binary data is encoded in a text format is up to you. For example, you could encode it as hex, or base64.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. PHP SHA256 function generate a string. You know what is the format of that string?

Comment: @Aegidius: You should consult the PHP documentation. For example. this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php - talks about returning either raw binary data or a lower case hex string.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. Thank you :D